# Motivating questions of real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, self-learning, math-history

In reading Galois theory, I have found it especially useful to keep in mind the historical questions that motivated its construction (the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) gives a nice summary of the kind of context that I found helpful).

What are similar motivating questions that I can keep in mind when reading real analysis, in particular while reading Baby Rudin? (Baby Rudin covers a lot of topics. I'd find context most useful for the elementary topology that's used (set properties such as open/closed, compactness, Cauchy sequences).)

Applications are also useful (e.g. cryptography was good to keep in mind for group theory and Galois theory) but I am looking more for motivating *mathematical* context. Not "why do people care?" but "why *did* people care?"

[In particular, this context is helpful to avoid searching for structure that doesn't exist. For instance, in Galois theory we have definitions involving general automorphism groups, but in practice maybe we only care about a common subset of them that we can reason about. I'd be interested to see similar answers for other areas of mathematics as well.]

Comment: I recommend Stillwell's book: https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Real_Numbers.html?id=VPe8BAAAQBAJ He does a good job motivating with history and such (he writes math history) and I have read his books "Elements of Algebra" and "Elements of Number Theory" and found them very good.

I think that maybe it is harder to give a nice motivation for everything in a book like Baby Rudin since (I think) unlike Galois theory where one can try to lay out the ideas that were developed over a short period of time, analysis has been developing for a long time and what we have has been refined.